# React-Select Creatable hide only create new.. message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Can I hide only create new option from the dropdown when using React-Select Creatable. I want to show other suggestion as usual and want to keep creatable functionality of creating new tag as well. Just dont want to show what user is typing in the dropdown menu.

Edit: Adding a example code for React-Select:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/lib/Creatable';
const colourOptions = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]


export default class CreatableMulti extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  formatCreate = (inputValue) => {
    return (<p> Add: {inputValue}</p>); 
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isMulti
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={colourOptions}
        formatCreateLabel={this.formatCreate}
        createOptionPosition={"first"}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Also here is a sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wqm0z1wlxl

when you type I want it shows a Add:  plus all other filtered suggestions. I want to remove add part from it keeping rest of the functionality.

Hope this will help now.

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far in your question?

Comment: Do you have any code

Comment: Just to synthesize what you want if I understood it well, you want to have the `Add:` option without the word that the user is typing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to replace the option `Add: myValue` you can use the props `formatCreateLabel` in your `CreatableSelect` as following:

```
formatCreateLabel={() => `Add`}
```

[Here a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qx5090n16) with the previous code applied to the example you gave.
You can consult the documentation right [here](https://react-select.com/props#creatable-props) to understand the behaviour of this particular props.

Comment: Thanks @Laura I saw your comment today. But I have already used the approach mentioned by you to achieve my result. Thanks for the answer maybe it will help others with the same problem.

Comment: For those who are not aware you can paste markup as well as it's JSX:
          formatCreateLabel={(userInput) => (
            <div>
              <div> nothing found for {userInput}&rdquo;</div>
              <button>
                + Add new
              </button>
            </div>
          )}